# Primeng Dropdown not binding the options in Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-forms

I am trying to bind the primeng dropdown in the Array of form in Angular 7. But the given options are not getting bind.

If am same using out side of form its getting bind. Can you help me to resolve this. what mistake I did in it.

Here is the Code at stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-d7vksr?file=package.json

Comment: Do you want the array to be populated in Select drop down under credentials ?

Comment: yes. It is the Formarray @Raahul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try these

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="published"> Published
      <div *ngIf="form.controls.published.value">
        <h2>Credentials</h2>
        <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>
        <div formArrayName="credentials" *ngFor="let creds of form.get('credentials').controls; let i = index">
          <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
            <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
            <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
              <p-dropdown formControlName="car" [options]="cars" placeholder="Select a Brand"></p-dropdown>
          </ng-container>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div (click)="formData()"> SUBMIT </div> 
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
    form: FormGroup;
    creds :FormArray;
    cars:any[]=[];
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            published: true,
            credentials: this.fb.array([]),
        });
        this.creds  = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray
        this.cars = [
            {label: 'Audi', value: 'Audi'},
            {label: 'BMW', value: 'BMW'},
            {label: 'Fiat', value: 'Fiat'},
            {label: 'Ford', value: 'Ford'},
            {label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda'},
            {label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'},
            {label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'},
            {label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'},
            {label: 'VW', value: 'VW'},
            {label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'}
        ];
    }

    addCreds() {
        const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
        creds.push(this.fb.group({
            username: '',
            password: '',
            car: []
        }));
    }       

    formData(){
        console.log(this.form.value);
    }  
}
```

Comment: the above you have given is not wokring.

Comment: If still you have facing any issue then tell me i will always ready for happily